# How can I get the Bluetooth status (on / off) on an Android phone using ADB?

Tags: adb, androidphone

I found some answers related to Bluetooth using ADB. But all of to turn on/off Bluetooth using ADB.

My requirement is like get the current Bluetooth status on the phone.  If it is in the off state, turn on Bluetooth and vice versa.

Comment: This could best be answered on Android Stack Exchange. Request a migration

Comment: *"But all of to turn on/off Bluetooth using ADB."* is ***incomprehensible***. Can you [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76958388/edit)? But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, I emailed you I guess I wasn't specific in the subject lol.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ADB 'get global' command to read the Bluetooth status for an Android phone using this command:

```
adb shell settings get global bluetooth_on
```